# Proof of proposition 9.12 in Axler

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

The proof started out with assuming
$$
(T_C-\lambda I)^j(u+iv)=(T_C-\lambda I)^{j-1}((T_C-\lambda I)(u+iv))=0,
$$
where $T_C$ is the complexification of $T \in \mathcal L(V)$. So, 
$$
(T_C-\lambda I)(u+iv)=(Tu-au+bv)+i(Tv-av-bu)
$$ 
and 
$$
(T_C-\bar{\lambda} I)(u+iv)=(Tu-au+bv)-i(Tv-av-bu),
$$ 
where $\lambda=a+bi$. The part I don't understand is the proof proceeds to imply that
$$
(T_C-\bar{\lambda} I)^{j-1}((Tu-au+bv)-i(Tv-av-bu))=0.
$$ 
Why is that?

Comment: $u+iv$ is the eigenvector and $\lambda$ is its complex eigenvalue, so...

Comment: The phrase within the quotation marks in the question above does not appear in the book.

Comment: @SheldonAxler It was my bad, I should've been more careful with quoting, I have edited the question to match with the text in the book.

Comment: He is going from $(T_{\mathbb{C}}-\overline{\lambda}I)^j(\mathbf{w})$ to $(T_{\mathbb{C}}-\overline{\lambda}I)^{j-1}\Bigl((T_{\mathbb{C}}-\overline{\lambda}I)(\mathbf{w})\Bigr)$, and then evaluating the inside. That is, going from $f^{j}(u)$ to $f^{j-1}(f(u))$, and then substituting the value of $f(u)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm aware of that, but the proof started out with $$(T_{\mathbb{C}}-\lambda I)^{j-1}\Bigl((T_{\mathbb{C}}-\lambda I)(\mathbf{w})\Bigr)=0$$ not its conjugate correspondent.

Comment: @DangDang Note that for transformations $S,T,$ $\overline{ST} = \bar S \bar T$. Note also that $\bar{T_{\mathbb C}} = T_{\mathbb C}$

Comment: You said “the part I don’t understand is...” The identity for the value of $T_{\mathbb{C}}-\overline{\lambda}I$ evaluated at the vector is in the display before you say “the part I don’t understand”, thus implying that you **do** understand it. If what you are now saying is that you did not in fact understand that identity, then perhaps you need to fix your question rather than be concerned that you got the answer for what you asked, rather than what you *meant* to ask.

Comment: Because it’s just the conjugate of the initial identity, as indicated by Omnomnomnom.

Comment: @DangDang Thank you for editing the question to remove the inaccurate quote.